# How to create a read-only RAM disk on macOS from the command line?

Tags: command-line, memory, mount, diskutil, hdiutil

On macOS Catalina, a RAM disk with 512MB space can be created with the following command:

```
diskutil eraseVolume HFS+ "RAMDisk" `hdiutil attach -nomount ram://1048576`
```

On Ubuntu, a RAM disk and its read-only shadow can be created by:

```
mount -t tmpfs -o size=512m tmpfs /mnt/ramdisk
mount -t aufs -o br:/mnt/ramdisk=ro none /mnt/readonly
```

So how can I create a read-only RAM disk on macOS Catalina with command line like this, or create a read-only shadow of existing RAM disk?

Comment: Since you're using **macOS Catalina** why not use **APFS** instead of **HFS+**? After all **macOS Catalina** uses **APFS**. The following _command_ works for me: `diskutil partitionDisk $(hdiutil attach -nomount ram://1048576) 1 GPTFormat APFS 'RAMDisk' '100%'` One advantage, while somewhat negligible as a **RAM** _disk_, **APFS** is faster. It also has less initial overhead, e.g. on a 512 MB _disk_ **HFS+** already uses 12.6 MB and **APFS** only uses 25 K. Percentage wise that's a big difference.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Get the device number of the RAM disk: `diskutil list` (e.g. disk3)

   Add some content to the RAM disk .
2. Unmount the volume: `diskutil umount disk3`
3. Mount the RAM disk read-only: `diskutil mount readOnly /dev/disk3`.

Apply the disk number according to your environment!

- `unmount/mount` works for an **HFS+** disk (in case of a RAM disk)/volume or an APFS volume only
- `unmountDisk/mountDisk` works for **HFS+** disks and **APFS** container schemes.

If you format the RAMDisk as APFS container and one APFS volume

```
diskutil partitionDisk $(hdiutil attach -nomount ram://1048576) 1 GPTFormat APFS 'RAMDisk' '100%'
```

you can either mount the APFS container scheme or the APFS volume:

1. Get the device number of the RAM disk's container scheme: `diskutil list` (e.g. disk4)
2. Unmount the volume: `diskutil umountDisk disk4`
3. Mount the RAM disk read-only: `diskutil mountDisk readOnly /dev/disk4`

or the RAM disk's APFS volume:

2. Unmount the volume: `diskutil umount disk4s1`
3. Mount the RAM disk read-only: `diskutil mount readOnly /dev/disk4s1`

---

As one-liner for an HFS+ volume with the unique name *RAMDisk*:

```
RD=$(diskutil list | awk '/RAMDisk/ { print $5 }'); diskutil umount $RD; diskutil mount readOnly $RD; exit
```

As one-liner for an APFS volume with the unique name *RAMDisk*:

```
RD=$(diskutil list | awk '/RAMDisk/ { print $7 }'); diskutil umount $RD; diskutil mount readOnly $RD; exit
```

---

Thanx to [user3439894](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/115523/user3439894) for all his hints & comments...

Comment: There was a question posted May 17 2020 asking how to create a RAM disk so it can survive a restart. Now that comment or thread appears to be missing. If this is the response could you please reference the question in your answer. Thanks.

Comment: @John It was an answer (still visible to users with more than 10k rep) to the question here but deleted subsequently (*This doesn‘t answer the question asked above, please use the „Ask Question“ button for new questions. – nohillside♦ yesterday*) Body: **Just curious if there is a way to create said RAMDisk so that it survives a restart, it would have great benefits of being able to eradicate an internal HD/SSD of Malware, various system problems**. Feel free to ask this question! ;-)