# RAM Disk Surviving a Restart

Tags: macos, memory

Just curious if there is a way to create [said RAM Disk](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/380227/how-to-create-a-read-only-ram-disk-on-macos-from-the-command-line) so that it survives a restart, it would have great benefits of being able to eradicate an internal HD/SSD of Malware, various system problems.

Comment: Do you mean a "bootable" RAM disk?

Comment: The short answer is: **No**